# copy a transparent image over another image (imagecopyresample)

Tags: php, image

I have a problem with copying a transparent image over another image.

I have 2 base64-strings containing an image: newMedia is a photo, and newDrawing is a drawing (in different colors) with a transparent background. I want to copy newDrawing **over** newMedia. Everything works, but the problem is that a black background is added to newDrawing in stead of a transparent background. To fix this, I added the imagecolortransparent-stuff etc..

It works for 99%! The only problem is with black colors. In my app, you can draw with black/white/blue/yellow/... "markers" over an image. All the colors work, except for black. I will add a screenshot to show.

Anyone has an idea to fix this? The function in the code-sample, I found it on php.net.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct){
    // creating a cut resource
    $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);

    // copying relevant section from background to the cut resource
    imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);

    // copying relevant section from watermark to the cut resource
    imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);

    // insert cut resource to destination image
    imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct);
}

if(isset($_POST['base64Media']) && isset($_POST['base64Drawing'])){

    $media = explode(',',$_POST['base64Media'],2);

    $drawing = explode(',',$_POST['base64Drawing'],2);

    $responseMedia = base64_decode($media[1]);

    $responseDrawing = base64_decode($drawing[1]);

    $responseMedia = imagecreatefromstring($responseMedia);

    $responseDrawing = imagecreatefromstring($responseDrawing);

    $newMedia = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($responseMedia),imagesy($responseMedia));

    imagecopyresampled($newMedia,$responseMedia,0,0,0,0,imagesx($newMedia),imagesy($newMedia),imagesx($responseMedia),imagesy($responseMedia));

    $newDrawing = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($responseDrawing),imagesy($responseDrawing));

    $black = imagecolorallocate($newDrawing,0,0,0);

    imagecolortransparent($newDrawing,$black);

    imagealphablending($newDrawing,false);

    imagesavealpha($newDrawing,true);

    imagecopyresampled($newDrawing,$responseDrawing,0,0,0,0,imagesx($newDrawing),imagesy($newDrawing),imagesx($responseDrawing),imagesy($responseDrawing));

    imagecopymerge_alpha($newMedia,$newDrawing,0,0,0,0,imagesx($newDrawing),imagesy($newDrawing),100);

    header('Content-type:image/png');

    imagepng($newMedia);

};

?>
```

**Link to image =>** [All the colors are displayed correctly, except for black (in the top left corner).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aezE.png)